# How do I ignore event subscribers when serializing an object?

Tags: c#, .net, events, serialization, binaryformatter

When the following class is serialized with a `BinaryFormatter`, any objects subscribing to the `Roar` event will also be serialized, since references to those objects are held by the EventHandler delegate.

```
[Serializable]
public class Lion
{
    public event EventHandler Roar;

    public string Name { get; set; }
    public float Fluffiness { get; set; }

    public Lion(string name, float fluffiness)
    {
        Name = name;
        Fluffiness = fluffiness;
    }

    public void Poke()
    {
        Roar(); // Could be null, etc..
    }
}
```

**How would you stop event subscribers being serialized as part of the object graph starting with a Lion?**

Putting the `[NonSerializable]` attribute on the `event` will not compile.

---

Note: I'm answering my own question since I think it might be useful to have the information on the site!

> FAQ: It's also perfectly fine to ask and answer your own question, but pretend you're on Jeopardy: phrase it in the form of a question.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

You have to include "`field:`" as part of the `[NonSerialized]` attribute on the `event`.

i.e.:

```
[field: NonSerialized]
public event EventHandler Roar;
```

Comment: Thanks. But why is that?

Comment: It is because System.NonSerializedAttribute has a constraint on it: it can only be applied to fields!