# SerializationException add EventHandler

Tags: c#, events, serialization

I get a SerializationException when I add an EventHandler:

```
public interface IPlugin
{
   ...
   event EventHandler<Event1Args> Event1;
   event EventHandler<Event2Args> Event2;
}

[Serializable()]
public class Plugin : MarshalByRefObject, IPlugin
{
    [field:NonSerialized]
    public event EventHandler<Event1Args> Event1;
    [field:NonSerialized]
    public event EventHandler<Event2Args> Event2;
}

public class Test
{
   public void Method()
   {
      IPlugin p = Plugins.GetPlugin("test");
      try
      {
          p.Event1 += (sender,args) => Console.Writeline("Test Event");
      }
      catch (Exception e)
      {
          /* here comes the SerializationException: the type
             TestNamespace.Test in Assembly "TestNamespace.Test,Version,..." 
             is not marked serializable.
          */
      }
   }
}
```

At runtime, the `IPlugin` is an instance of the class `Plugin`, I can add the `[field:NonSerialized]` in that class, but not in the interface. But this did not change anything.
I do not have the english VisualStudio so maybe the exception message is not 100% correct.
My original exception message is:

> System.Runtime.Serialization.SerializationException: Der Typ
>   "TestNamespace.Test+<>c__DisplayClass5_0" in Assembly "TestNamespace,
>   Version=2.1.6376.11505, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null" ist
>   nicht als serialisierbar gekennzeichnet.
>
> Server stack trace:     bei
>   System.Runtime.Serialization.FormatterServices.InternalGetSerializableMembers(RuntimeType
>   type)    bei
>   System.Runtime.Serialization.FormatterServices.GetSerializableMembers(Type
>   type, StreamingContext context)    bei
>   System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.WriteObjectInfo.InitMemberInfo()
>   bei
>   System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.WriteObjectInfo.InitSerialize(Object
>   obj, ISurrogateSelector surrogateSelector, StreamingContext context,
>   SerObjectInfoInit serObjectInfoInit, IFormatterConverter converter,
>   ObjectWriter objectWriter, SerializationBinder binder)    bei
>   System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.ObjectWriter.Write(WriteObjectInfo
>   objectInfo, NameInfo memberNameInfo, NameInfo typeNameInfo)    bei
>   System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.ObjectWriter.Serialize(Object
>   graph, Header[] inHeaders, __BinaryWriter serWriter, Boolean fCheck)
>   bei
>   System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.BinaryFormatter.Serialize(Stream
>   serializationStream, Object graph, Header[] headers, Boolean fCheck)
>   bei
>   System.Runtime.Remoting.Channels.CrossAppDomainSerializer.SerializeMessageParts(ArrayList
>   argsToSerialize)    bei
>   System.Runtime.Remoting.Messaging.SmuggledMethodCallMessage..ctor(IMethodCallMessage
>   mcm)    bei
>   System.Runtime.Remoting.Messaging.SmuggledMethodCallMessage.SmuggleIfPossible(IMessage
>   msg)    bei
>   System.Runtime.Remoting.Channels.CrossAppDomainSink.SyncProcessMessage(IMessage
>   reqMsg)
>
> Exception rethrown at [0]:     bei
>   System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.HandleReturnMessage(IMessage
>   reqMsg, IMessage retMsg)    bei
>   System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.PrivateInvoke(MessageData&
>   msgData, Int32 type)    bei
>   TestNamespace.Plugins.IPlugin.add_Event1(EventHandler`1 value)    bei
>   TestNamespace.Test.d__5.MoveNext() in
>   C:\xxx\Test.cs:Zeile 14.

The plugins are created in another `AppDomain` and with `AggregateCatalog` and `CompositionContainer`, so while debugging I see the IPlugin instance is a remote proxy instance. I don´t know if that could be the problem.

I already tried marking the Test class as `[Serializable()]`, but that did not change anything.

Comment: What is IPlugin? I think it's not part of the .Net Framework

Comment: Since you're using `BinaryFormatter` try marking the events as non-serialized as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2308629/3744182) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1173669/3744182).

Comment: IPlugin is the interace in my example.
I do not use `BinaryFormatter` on purpose. Is that the default Formatter for AppDomains? I can´t mark the events, because they are declared in the interface and there I can´t add the attribute.